# Random Matrix Theory, semicircular law, and Bai-Yin Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

I am trying to find a proof for the following lower bound Bai-Yin theorem.

*Theorem:* For an ensemble of Wigner matrices $(W_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$, we have for any $\epsilon>0$, almost surely,
\begin{align*}
||W_n||>(2-\epsilon)\sqrt{n}
\end{align*}
for large enough $n$. Here we denote the operator norm of matrix $A$ with $||A||$. In fact, we have almost surely
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf||W_n||/\sqrt{2}\geq 2
\end{align*}
**My question:** Only thing I found on the internet was the following proof fragment, which looks kind of strange for me. For instance, the used function $g$ seems to be not defined for some arguments ($x=2-\epsilon$) and overall I am not able to follow the argumentation.

*Proof:*
By the semicircular law, we know that the empirical spectral distribution of $(1/\sqrt{n})W_n$ converges to a semicircular distribution almost surely. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $g:\mathbb{R\rightarrow}[0,1]$ be a continuous function with $g(x)=1$ if $|x|<2-\epsilon$ and $g(x)=0$ if $|x|>2-\epsilon/2$.

If $||W_n||<(2-\epsilon)\sqrt{2}$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)d\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}W_n}(x)=1.
\end{align*}
But we also see that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)d\mu_{sc}(x)<1.
\end{align*}
This means that we can almost surely find $N$ such that
\begin{align*}
||W_n||>(2-\epsilon)\sqrt{n}
\end{align*}
for any $n>N$.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. First consider the (real-valued) *random variable*

$$X_n=\int_\mathbb{R} h \,d\mu_{W_n/\sqrt{n}}.$$

where $h(x)=1$ if $|x|\le 2-\varepsilon$ and $h(x)=0$ if $|x|> 2-\varepsilon$. $X_n$ is counting the fraction of eigenvalues of $W_n$ inside the interval $[(-2+\varepsilon)\sqrt{n},(2-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}]$.

Now the following events all happen with probability 1. From the semicircular law, $X_n$ converges to the random variable equal to the mass of the semicircular distribution on the interval $[-2+\varepsilon,2-\varepsilon]$. Since it is a (deterministic) number strictly less than 1, $X_n<1$ for all but finitely many $n$. Recalling the interpretation of $X_n$, this means that for all but finitely many $n$, $W_n$ has an eigenvalue of magnitude larger than $(2-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}$, i.e. $\lVert W_n\rVert>(2-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}$.

---

There is one flaw in our proof: We need to take a *continuous* test function $h$ to apply the convergence results of the semicircular law. However, the same idea works by picking *some* continuous approximation $g$ of $h$ that satisfies $g(x)=1$ if $|x|\le 2-\varepsilon$, $g(x)=0$ if $|x|>2-\varepsilon/2$ and $g(x)\in[0,1]$ inbetween. Now $X_n$ only provides an *upper bound* on the fraction of eigenvalues inside $[(-2+\varepsilon)\sqrt{n},(2-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}]$. However, you can check that $X_n$ still converges a.s. to a number strictly less than 1, so this still means that a.s. $\lVert W_n\rVert>(2-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}$ for all but finitely many $n$.

---

Note that if you do not have the semicircular law, there are also more direct proofs under additional assumptions on the boundedness of the entries (see e.g. [Proposition 32](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/254a-notes-3-the-operator-norm-of-a-random-matrix/) of Tao's set of notes).